# aws route53 get-health-check --health-check-id does not return the associated cloudwatch alarm details

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-route53

As per AWS Documentation, its mentioned that get-health-check will return CloudWatchAlarmConfiguration also.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/get-health-check.html

But its missing the CloudWatchAlarmConfiguration when i queried even though I have CW alarm attached to this heathcheck id.

```
{
    "HealthCheck": {
        "Id": "HEALTH_CHECK_ID",
        "CallerReference": "ID",
        "HealthCheckConfig": {
            "IPAddress": "EIP",
            "Port": 80,
            "Type": "HTTP",
            "RequestInterval": 30,
            "FailureThreshold": 3,
            "MeasureLatency": false,
            "Inverted": false,
            "Disabled": false,
            "EnableSNI": false
        },
        "HealthCheckVersion": 1
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get the alarms configured for a route 53 health check ID?

Answer (score 0):

Your R53 health check is of type `HTTP`.

The command returns associated alarms when the type is `CLOUDWATCH_METRIC`. In that case R53 uses a [CloudWatch alarm for health assessment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints.html#dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints-cloudwatch), not HTTP:

> When you create a health check that is **based on a CloudWatch alarm**, Route 53 monitors the data stream for the corresponding alarm instead of monitoring the alarm state.

Also from [get-health-check](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/get-health-check.html), the `CloudWatchAlarmConfiguration` is:

> A complex type that contains information about the **CloudWatch alarm that Amazon Route 53 is monitoring for this health check**.

Comment: Is there a way to get list of configured alarm for a Health Check ID, even if the type is HTTP?

Comment: @Deepan I think the alarms you are after are created outside of R53, but using R53 metrics in cloudwatch?